# Fire and forget DB logging with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, mysql, ado.net

I am using MySQL with ASP.NET and log some user request to DB. Is it possible to do this logging without blocking the main page life cycle? I've read about some async. with ADO.NET but most are focused on waiting a reply from the async. request. Is there a way to implement this without ever waiting a reply from the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a fire and forget scenario you could spawn a new thread and never block the main thread waiting for it to complete:

```
new Thread(() => {
    // use ADO.NET to do the database query
}).Start();
```

Comment: @paulsimmons, I would use the [connection pool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html). Simply wrap the connection in a `using` clause and leave the underlying framework handle the connections.

Comment: oh yeah, actually i was referring just to that, i think brand new was an overrated choice of words :) so what i was trying to say; should i get a new connection object within this thread or continue using the one in the main thread?

Comment: @paulsimmons, everytime you write a query to your database wrap everything in `using` clauses passing the same connection string for the `MySqlConnection`. This way you will take advantage of the connection pooling. Don't reuse anything. Actually your data access code should be in a DAL so you shouldn't event be bothering with this in your code behind. You should only invoke the underlying method on your DAL.